# unlock android emulator from cmd line

Tags: android, emulation

I would like to run android emulator from cmd line - unlock it and control it. 
Is this possible ?

I know how to operate from eclipse?

Comment: Ican run emulator, i want to unlock it :)

Comment: @KK What do you mean exactly by "unlocking"?

Answer (score 10):

On emulator try `adb shell input keyevent 82`. This keyevent execute KEYCODE_MENU and unlock a screen.

Answer (score 7):

You can interact with the emulator via its console interface.

If you ever wondered why your emulator started with a number like 5554 - that's because that's the port the emulator listening on.

You can find the port for running emulators with the adb devices command. It will have output like this:

C:>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
So you can connect to the emulator using a command like:

telnet localhost 5554
If you connect successfully you'll get an OK prompt and you can start entering commands.

There are various commands but the one we are interested in is event to simulate hardware events. We can unlock the screen by pressing Menu which we emulate with the following command:

event send EV_KEY:KEY_MENU:1 EV_KEY:KEY_MENU:0

Comment: this doesn't do anything when we try to run this against an emulator. Did I miss something? Connected to emulator via telnet and just copy and pasted that command, but the menu doesn't open.

Comment: Also what are the 0 and 1 values? Do these correspond to ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the monkeyrunner tool which will allow you to do this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use **[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** this script will do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.unlock()
```