# How to send key events to a headless emulator in an instrumentation test?

Tags: android, testing, build-automation, emulation, instrumentation

We are currently working on an instrumentation test suite which runs on our build server, but while the tests pass on a dev machine using a normal Android emulator, the builds fail on the build server since there we only run a headless emulator with the `-no-window` flag.

The failure occurs when trying to invoke the `InstrumentationTestCase.sendKeys()` method to programmatically open the options menu. The error is:

> Permission denied: injecting key event from pid 646 uid 10026 to window Window{43d55100  paused=false} owned by uid 1000

We then found out that there's a `INJECT_EVENTS` permission, but setting it in the manifest had no effect. In fact in the log we saw this output:

> Not granting permission android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS to package com.qype.radar (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x6644)

Does that mean this permission is useless?

We also tried to let the instrumentation test app and the app under test share the same Linux user ID using `android:sharedUserId` and run in the same process (`android:process` -- we weren't sure if that was already the case), but still no luck.

Does this mean it's currently impossible to run instrumentations which contain key events on a headless emulator, or are we missing something?

Comment: `INJECT_EVENTS` is a perfectly valid permission, but one that can only be held by firmware, not by SDK applications.

Comment: bummer. so what's our best bet? Didn't Google think about running tests on a build server?

Comment: I just restarted the emulator using the -wipe-data flag, then the build passed ONCE, then the emulator crashed, restarted it again, now the build is failing again... this is all so flaky :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with my test on the Hudson server. In my case the problem I solved by suggestion from Android SDK:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html#UITestTroubleshooting

Important was that I had to enable permissions for main application too.

Comment: hey great, how could we miss that? We think the problem is actually the keyguard -- it prevents sendKeys() to work correctly.

Comment: What was the solution? The section has been deleted from that page :(

Comment: If I remember correctly, the solution was to programmatically disable the keyguard, since it will be active after every emulator/phone boot. Have a look at this snippet: http://pastebin.com/v0deQGpT You will want to remove this code from a production app of course; it disables the keyguard permanently until the next boot.

Comment: Just for the record, Christopher's answer is the better one, since it doesn't require this hack. As far as I know, the Android plug-in for Hudson/Jenkins will also disable the keyguard automatically for you.

Answer (score 17):

I run the emulator without `-no-window` on headless machines by first running an Xvnc instance (i.e. fake X server) then starting the emulator in that `DISPLAY`.

More accurately, I get the [Xvnc](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin) and [Android Emulator](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) Jenkins plugins to do this for me.

Unfortunately, unlocking the screen is still a concern before injecting UI events, but this is (hackily) resolved by automatically running a command like this (similar to [this other answer you've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332948/unlock-android-emulator-from-cmd-line/2335013#2335013)):
`echo "event send EV_KEY:KEY_MENU:1 EV_KEY:KEY_MENU:0" | nc -q1 localhost 5554`

---

**Edit:**
I discovered that this method is far more reliable:
`adb shell input keyevent 82`

[Some info](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java#271) about keycode 82.

Comment: that sounds really interesting, we'll check that out, thanks!