# Robotium in -no-window Emulator throws Click can not be completed

Tags: android, android-emulator, robotium

I'm Using Robtium 4.1

When i run my Robotium test on an Emulator which is visible i can click on an Button using:

```
    final Button startButton = (Button) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(
            com.coop.R.id.btn_start);
    solo.clickOnView(startQuizButton);
```

Doing the same thing in an Emulator which was launched invisible with the -no-window Option i get the exception :

[INFO] android.device parameter set to emulator
[INFO] emulator-5554_AVD_for_Galaxy_Tab_10_1_unknown_sdk :   Running instrumentation tests in com.company.abc.app.test
[INFO] emulator-5554_AVD_for_Galaxy_Tab_10_1_unknown_sdk :     Run started: com.company.abc.app.test, 1 tests:
[INFO] emulator-5554_AVD_for_Galaxy_Tab_10_1_unknown_sdk :       FAILURE:com.company.abc.app.SingleChoiceTest#testappType
[INFO] emulator-5554_AVD_for_Galaxy_Tab_10_1_unknown_sdk :       junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Click can not be completed!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:85)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:157)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:131)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnView(Solo.java:879)
at com.company.abc.app.BaseappModuleRobotiumTest.checkIntroductionActivity(BaseappModuleRobotiumTest.java:155)
at com.company.abc.app.BaseappModuleRobotiumTest.testappType(BaseappModuleRobotiumTest.java:174)

I read the "Why do text and button clicks get wrong?" And checked back again, still same problem to me :/

I looked in [sources on Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.android.robotium/robotium-solo/4.0/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Clicker.java#72), which catches an SecurityException. Why just in -no-window Mode this gets thrown ?

Any help on this ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I bet that emulator is run with locked screen. Every click in robotium is finally executed as click on screen (more precisely method obtain from class MotionEvent is performed).
You cannot click on screen, if there is application from another process on the screen.

You have to find the way, how to unlock screen before test execution.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214531/how-to-send-key-events-to-a-headless-emulator-in-an-instrumentation-test#answer-3366443) can help you.
You can also run some vnc server on that emulator, connect and check, if this is really related to locked screen, nevertheless I'm 99% sure that's the issue.